# How to add a new column that summarize rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, aggregate-functions

I have two issues  :

1. I used 'Rollup' function to add Totals per Month and Year and I would like to change 'NULL' into grand_total as in the attached screenshot
2. I dont know how to add a new column that will summarize values starting from the second row

**Please see attached screenshot of the results I need to receive and an example for a code from my side with a screenshot of the source output** : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B70o.png
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2x8K.png

```
Select Year(Modifieddate) AS Year,
       MONTH(modifieddate) as Month,
       Sum(linetotal) as Sum_price
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
Group by  rollup( Year(Modifieddate),MONTH(modifieddate))
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
Select Year(Modifieddate) AS Year,
       coalesce(convert(varchar(255), month(modifieddate)), 'Grand Total') as Month,
       Sum(linetotal) as Sum_price,
       sum(sum(linetotal)) over (partition by Year(Modifieddate)
                                 order by coalesce(month(modifieddate), 100)
                                ) as ytd_sum_price
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
Group by rollup( Year(Modifieddate), month(modifieddate))
```

The `coalesce()` in the `order by` is to put the summary row last for the cumulative sum.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff: How to remove overall sum row in your query because it needs year wise sum.

Comment: @RahulBiswas . . . If you want more control over the grouping, use `GROUPING SETS()`:  `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (YEAR(ModifiedDate), MONTH(ModifiedDate)), (YEAR(ModifiedDate))`.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff: thanks for your response. Yes GROUPING SETS is the better option here. I used it for this question. My answer is My submitted answer was given below.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Select Year(Modifieddate) AS Year, MONTH(modifieddate) as Month, Sum(linetotal) as Sum_price 
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
Group by rollup( Year(Modifieddate),MONTH(modifieddate))
UNION 
Select Year(Modifieddate) AS Year, 'grand_total' as Month, Sum(linetotal) as Sum_price 
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
Group by Year(Modifieddate)
```

Comment: Hey :) @ettiene thanks. I tried to execute your code and I received this error:   **Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'grand_total' to data type int.** Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Well, your column Month in the first SELECT is an integer, so 'grand_total' in the second select should also be an integer. This is impossible, but maybe you can convert the column Month in the first SELECT to varchar like this: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(100,MONTH(modifieddate)) as Month`

Comment: If your question is answered with this, please mark the question as answered

Comment: if your logged in, there is a check link to click on left of the answer I gave

Answer (score 0):

```
-- SQL SERVER
SELECT t.OrderYear
     , CASE WHEN t.OrderMonth IS NULL THEN 'Grand Total' ELSE CAST(t.OrderMonth AS VARCHAR(20)) END b
     , t.MonthlySales
     , MAX(t.cum_total) cum_total
FROM (SELECT
    YEAR(OrderDate) AS OrderYear,
    MONTH(OrderDate) AS OrderMonth,
    SUM(SubTotal) AS MonthlySales,
    SUM(SUM(SubTotal)) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) cum_total
    
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate)))) t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((t.OrderYear
     , t.OrderMonth
     , t.MonthlySales), t.OrderYear);
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=e6cd2ba8114bd1d86b8c61b1453cafcf

Answer (score 0):

To build one @GordonLinoff's answer, **you are really supposed to use the `GROUPING()` function** to check whether you are dealing with the grouping column. This behaves better in the face of nullable columns.

```sql
Select case when grouping(Year(Modifieddate)) = 0
         then Year(Modifieddate)
         else 'Grand Total' end AS Year,
       case when grouping(month(modifieddate)) = 0
         then convert(varchar(255), month(modifieddate))
         else 'Grand Total' end as Month,
       Sum(linetotal) as Sum_price,
       sum(sum(linetotal)) over (
            partition by
               grouping(Year(Modifieddate)),
               grouping(month(modifieddate)),
               Year(Modifieddate)
            order by month(modifieddate)
                                ) as ytd_sum_price
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
Group by rollup( Year(Modifieddate), month(modifieddate));
```